# PyQt4: Save input to variable without new dialog box

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt4

I must say I am still very new to the PyQt4 module, so this question might be painfully obvious.  However, I have spent a good while trying to solve this particular problem and have run out of ideas.

Here is my code thus far:

```
...
self.btn = QtGui.QPushButton('Save Text', self)
self.btn.move(20, 20)
self.le = QtGui.QLineEdit(self)
self.le.move(130, 22)
self.btn.clicked.connect(self.save_text)
...
```

And then the function:

```
def save_text(self):
    text, ok = QtGui.QInputDialog.getText(self, 'Input', 'Type text:')
    filename = QtGui.QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self, 'Save File', '.')
    fname = open(filename, 'w')
    fname.write(self.le.setText(str(text)))
    fname.close()
```

This code works fine, but I am trying to refine it.  What I am trying to do is save the text in the main window's input field (the `self.le`) directly to a file.  Currently, whenever the `Save Text` button is pressed, it opens a new dialog and the user enters the text to save in the new dialog.  Essentially, I would like to be able to use `getText` with the `self.le` and save that to the `text` variable, but I have been unable to do so.  Is there any direct way to store text from the `self.le` to the `text` variable via a button click?  Or save it directly to the file?  I am running Python 2.7.

Answer (score 2):

if you wish to save the text of QlineEdit self.le to a file, you just need to use this

`text = self.le.text()`

so your save_text function becomes

```
def save_text(self):
    text, ok = self.le.text()   //basically access the QlineEdit self.le and use text() to access its text
    filename = QtGui.QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self, 'Save File', '.')
    fname = open(filename, 'w')
    fname.write(self.le.setText(str(text)))
    fname.close()
```

Comment: Thanks, I actually just figured out how to do what I needed to do.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found a much simpler way to accomplish what I have been trying to do.  Here is the code:

```
...
self.btn = QtGui.QPushButton('Save Text', self)
self.btn.move(20, 20)
self.btn.clicked.connect(self.save_text)

self.te = QtGui.QTextEdit(self)
self.te.resize(200,100)
self.te.move(130,22)
...
```

And then the function:

```
def save_text(self):
    text = self.te.toPlainText()
    filename = QtGui.QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self, 'Save File', '.')
    fname = open(filename, 'w')
    fname.write(str(text))
    fname.close()
```